# Selecting row with the greatest hexidecimal value

Tags: sql, select

I am looking for a way to select a single row from a MySQL table.
One of the columns contains a hexidecimal value and I only want to SELECT the row which contains the largest hex value.

So for instance there are three rows like:

```
id   hex_value   comments
 1   01          some comments...
 2   1A          some comments...
 3   03          some comments...
```

So the resultant returned rows contents would be id 2 as the value 1A is the greatest.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated.

Thank you
Mark

Comment: What is the type of a `hex_value` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the hexadecimal strings are the same length (as in your example), they are comparable as strings, so you can just sort them:

```
select id, hex_value, comments
from TheTable
order by hex_value desc
limit 1
```

Note: You need to use `desc` when sorting to get the highest value first.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY  UNHEX(hex_value) desc LIMIT 1
```

should work

Comment: That won't return a single row, it will just place the desired row last in the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ...
order by CONV(hex_value,16,10)
limit 1
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv

Comment: That will get the row with the lowest value, not the highest value.